# Maven install assembly exclusion

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-install-plugin

In my Maven project, I am using the *maven-assembly-plugin* bound to the *package* phase to create a distribution archive (*zip*) of the project. When I call *mvn clean install* to build & install the project, this archive gets installed into my local repository (*.m2*) as well. How can I exclude it from the installation? Or more generally, how can I exclude certain files/maven products from installation? I tried to relocate the assembly output out of the *target* directory but that wasn't the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `attach` property of the maven-assembly-plugin to `false`, see [the docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html#attach).
That way the file is generated but not attached to the project, excluding it from operations like `install` and `deploy`.

That being said, I don't recommend this as it can lead to unexpected behavior down the line.

Comment: This is exaclty what I was looking for. I have read the docs but somehow misunderstood the _attach_ property. Thank you!